# Create directories and files by given path with jar

Tags: java, jar, log4j2

I have a java maven project, which converts .json files to .yaml and vice versa. Long story short,I wrote method which creates resulting directory of converting process using path of where jar actually is. Then I created the method which creates files and writes there result of converting process to the /path_of_resulting_dir/file-name.json/.yaml. In case I run jar from my project in IntelliJ idea - everything is ok. However, when I run jar file from random folder on my desktop, nothing happens.

So, how can I correctly make jar to know if there are any files I should convert placed next to the jar file(e.g. C:\path_to_jar\SomeJarDir\jar.jar So files are in the SomeJarDir with a jar), or if there are any files which I access from path I write as jar argument need to be converted.

Link to the GitHub, where is my code placed(old version where I haven’t tried to make jar to know what to convert from any folder it’s placed, which works only if u run jar in IntelliJ idea):

https://github.com/foreverdumb/javaSprSum2021/tree/JavaSprSmrHmwrk/michaelProject

P.S. How can I force log4j to create log file next to jar?

Comment: Looks like you are using relative path for file creation. Try using absolute paths. In your case when you run the standalone jar the files would be created in different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program maybe using relative path, so when you run your program from different location, it will read the directory relative to itself. Either provide the path during runtime as user input or set the absolute path to the jar.

Comment: I'm back and if someone is interested in solving this question too here is the answer:
log4j2 conf file must have this:
basePath = ${./someDirName}
So, your log files will be stored next to the jar, don't forget to run your  jar from folder, e.g. /somePathToDir/someProgramme.jar